# JavaScript alternative for document.write()

Tags: javascript, html

For example, I have some function:

```
var inputA = document.getElementById("A").value;
var inputB = document.getElementById("B").value;
document.write("First input is: " + inputA + '<br />');
document.write("Second input is: " + inputB + '<br />');
```

So, in this case I use document.write(), but with several these functions it gets messed up. This document.write() overwrites my parent html page. How to set it up to open in a new page/tab. Or how to use document.close() in this situation in order to work properly.

Should I use some better method, which will also have the same functionality as this one. I want to set up a variable that will print a line of text, code, numbers etc. in the desired position of a page.

Comment: Use some container element and `innerHTML`.

Comment: @Quentin - that is not a really good dupe candidate... The answers there are all using only jQuery and don't really address the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `innerHTML`

```
<input type="text" id="A" value="some" />
<input type="text" id="B" value="other value" />
<div id="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var inputA = document.getElementById("A").value;
var inputB = document.getElementById("B").value;

var firstInput = "First input is: " + inputA + '<br />';
var secondInput = "First input is: " + inputB + '<br />';

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = firstInput + secondInput;
</script>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8P4D9/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of overwriting your whole page you should just update parts of it, for example.

```
<div id="myDiv">
</div>

<script>
  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = ("First input is: " + inputA + '<br />');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you will be able to do is to place that text in a specific element rather than just writing it to the document.

Assuming you have this in your HTML:

```
<div id="content" />
```

You can use something like this:

```
var str = "This is the content";
var elem = document.getElementById("content");
elem.innerHTML = str;
```

---

If all you are worried about is debugging your logic, you could always just use a `console.log()` to print something out to the JS console so you can take a look at it.